# How to authenticate Oracle login using encrypted password

Tags: oracle, authentication, database-administration

We are connecting to Oracle using KornShell (ksh) scripts, which use SQL*Plus to connect to Oracle. The Oracle database is on the same Solaris box. Currently, we are storing Oracle user id and password (plain text) in a file in the .ssh folder of the connecting user, with 400 permission bits.

The DBAs are objecting to this way of working, citing the fact that we are using plain text password for authentication. When we offered that we would encode the password using base64, they still did not like the idea, citing that we would still decrypt the password in the shell script and transmit the password over network.

Now, I want to understand this-

1. I have been reading that Oracle encrypts/hashes the password string, before transmitting it. I can not find the reference right now though, however, I still want to confirm my understanding. Is it really like this? We are on 11g r2, would that make a difference?
2. Would I be able to login to SQL*Plus without decrypting the password hash? e.g., DBAs set a password, pass on the hash to me. I put that in a file, and supply to SQL*Plus as a parameter.  Is there some way by which this kind of authentication work? I know some tools do allow that, if you encode using their tool, they are able to decrypt the value and use it for authentication. Does Oracle?

Help me fellas.

Answer (score 4):

Its been a while since doing this (and I don't have a linux box handy atm), but you can *try* this to hide details from ps:

```
echo password | sqlplus -s username@database @myscript.sql
```

Note that -s is silent mode for sqlplus.  I believe you can also put the password in a "protected" file (I use the term loosely, but set bits to 400) and cat the file, piping to sqlplus as above.

**Edit**: 
If the DBAs are really concerned with passwords, then how about using NO passwords.  You can try OS authentication, but you need some setup first.  For example:

--in Oracle, create new user

```
create user ops$batch_user IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;
grant connect to ops$batch_user;
```

-- in Unix (login as batch_user, or use su command)

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/11.2
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=DEV
sqlplus /
```

Note that no passwords are used since the user is authenticated by the os.  This is less complicated than Oracle wallet imo, but not perfect either.

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you connecting to the db? If you use `sqlplus user/password@database` from your commandline/script then you indeeed have a problem. The reason is, that you can easily see the password with the `ps` command.

Obfuscating it with `Base64` is not really an encryption, because `Base64` is a known algorithm for transfering binary data over the wire. This might baffle some, but certainly is not a safe way of sending a password.

What I do in this case, to avoid the password being shown int he process list, is that I write the password to a textfile with read only permission for the local user. Then I run sqlplus with nohup or in the background `sqlplus user@db < pwdfile` and immediately delete the file again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Oracle Wallets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cnctslsh.htm) for DB authentication.

Example of tuning may be found [here](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2006/08/sqlnetwallet_overridetrue.html).